# Determine real number exists for relation with square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers, square-numbers

We have $$\sqrt{x -2} = 3 -2\sqrt{x}$$.

I am to find whether a real number exists for this relation, and the real number that satisfies.

I start by squaring both sides, which yields:

$$x - 2 = 4x - 12\sqrt{x} + 9$$.

Whence:

$$ -3x = -12\sqrt{x} + 11 \\
\sqrt{x} = \frac{x}{4} + \frac{11}{12}.
$$

But once i get here i am stuck. How can i find whether a solution exists for x from here?

Comment: see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28x-2%29+%3D+3+-+2*sqrt%28x%29) for a solution, though you will not see the steps taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again: square both sides and solve the resulting quadratic. You'll get

$$x = \left( \frac{x}{4} + \frac{11}{12}\right)^{\! 2}$$

Remember to check your answers in the original question.

Comment: And then check for extraneous solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=\sqrt{x}$. Then,
$$ \sqrt{x} = \frac{x}{4} + \frac{11}{12}\\
\implies 0 = \frac{y^2}{4} -y + \frac{11}{12}
$$
You should be able to use the quadratic formula to solve for $y$ (check for extraneous solutions), and then don't forget to solve for $x$ from $y$.

Comment: From this and the quadratic formula i get $$y = 2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$. Is this on the right track? Plugging this in the original question doesn't seem to yield any use.

Comment: From the quadratic formula, you should get *two* solutions.